# How to append a value from exploded value in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The data is

```
data = [{"_id":"Inst001","Type":"AAAA", "Model001":[{"_id":"Mod001", "Name": "FFFF"},
                                                    {"_id":"Mod0011", "Name": "FFFF4"}]},
        {"_id":"Inst002", "Type":"BBBB", "Model001":[{"_id":"Mod002", "Name": "DDD"}]}]
```

Need to frame a dataframe as follows

| pid | _id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inst001 | Mod001 | FFFF |
| Inst001 | Mod0011 | FFFF4 |
| Inst002 | Mod002 | DDD |

The approach I had is

1. Need to explode "Model001"
2. Then need to append the main _id to this exploded dataframe. But how this append can be done in pyspark?

Is there any builtin method available in pyspark for the above problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nerdyGuy I have exploded the "Model001" but got stucked in appending the main _id to this exploded dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dataframe with a proper schema, and do `inline` on the `Model001` column:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data, 
    '_id string, Type string, Model001 array<struct<_id:string, Name:String>>'
).selectExpr('_id as pid', 'inline(Model001)')

df.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-------+-----+
|pid    |_id    |Name |
+-------+-------+-----+
|Inst001|Mod001 |FFFF |
|Inst001|Mod0011|FFFF4|
|Inst002|Mod002 |DDD  |
+-------+-------+-----+
```